# Compiler Error warning: library search path "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu" is unsafe for cross-compilation|

Tags: mysql, c, linux, gcc, cross-compiling

I'm using Kubuntu and trying to cross compile for raspberry pi with code:blocks, c and mysql.

I have set the compiler Flags `mysql_config --cflags` and the linker settings `mysql_config --libs` for mysql.

If i try to compile the first software, i get the error message:

> ||warning: library search path "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu" is unsafe
>   for cross-compilation|

This software compiles fine on a known good system.

The Compiler would create from buildroot and work fine without mysql.

this is the answer from knowing good system:

> pi@ubuntu:~$ echo `mysql_config --cflags`
>   -I/usr/include/mysql 
>   pi@ubuntu:~$ echo `mysql_config --libs`
>   -L/usr/lib -lmysqlclient -lpthread -lm -lrt -ldl

and this told me my system:

> student@student-O-E-M:/usr/lib$ echo `mysql_config --cflags`
>   -I/usr/include/mysql -DBIG_JOINS=1 -fno-strict-aliasing -g -DNDEBUG 
>   student@student-O-E-M:/usr/lib$ echo `mysql_config --libs`
>   -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lmysqlclient -lpthread -lz -lm -ldl

What should be done?

Comment: What Linux dostro is running on your RPi? Try [Buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/). It provides both RPi target and MySQL package.

Comment: Thanks for your Info. I use already Buildroot to create a little and fast operation system for the RPI. I found a additional error message in the build log last day.
`> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so: file not recognized: File format not recognized<`

I have already try to copy the /libmysqlclient.so from raspberry to the destination, but this doesn't work.

Comment: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so is a x86 file, so the error message is correct. Copying *.so files can fail, if they were compiled via different toolchains (ABI, floating point settings). It is always best to compile everything with one toolchain, like in the case with buildroot. If normal Buildroot fails to compile libmysqlclient, but other packages are working, I would write to BR's mailing list.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I had found my problem. I copy this files to /usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/ and not to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/. -.-° After this i get other missing files. I try to copy this files to, but i overwrite system files like libm.so and libz.so. Just my Computer would only boot to shell and many software would not start. I would try to copy the missing files from live dvd next week. Thanks for answer

Comment: here is the solution for this problem. I have change the linker path from mysql_config --libs to -L~/br/buildroot/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/ -lmysqlclient -lpthread -lz -lm -ldl
(to my buildroot path and it works)